# How to set up a lookup Field xml field creation in SharePoint Online in JSON

Tags: json, templates, sharepoint-online

I want to provide a list with a lookup field in the Template Script of SharePoint online.
One of the list is the "Participants list". In this list I want to creat a lookup field, which should reference the "Role Description" field in another list. I don't know where I get the ID of the target field and how the XML should be structured correctly.

Here is my JSON so far:

```
{
        "verb": "createSPList",
        "listName": "Project Participants interal and external",
        "templateType": 100,
        "subactions": [
            {
                "verb": "setDescription",
                "description": "Participants who will be in the project"
            },
            {
                "verb": "addSPLookupFieldXml",
                "schemaXml": "<Field Type=\"Lookup\" DisplayName=\"Role Description\" Required=\"FALSE\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" ShowField=\"Title\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"FALSE\" RelationshipDeleteBehavior=\"None\" ID=\"{?????} StaticName=\"ProjectRoles\" Name=\"ProjectRoles\" />",
                "targetListName": "Role Description",
                "addToDefaultView": true
            }
        ]
    }



 {
        "verb": "createSPList",
        "listName": "Role Description",
        "templateType": 100,
        "subactions": [
            {
                "verb": "setDescription",
                "description": "All description of the roles will be stored here"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Where I get the ID of the field if I create the list first. The ID change when you use the it again.

I hope you can help me with this issue.

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the ID of the target field. You can use ShowField to display column from the target list.

```
{
            "verb": "addSPLookupFieldXml",
            "schemaXml": "<Field Type=\"Lookup\" DisplayName=\"Role Description\" Required=\"FALSE\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" ShowField=\"{Here you can use name of the column you want to show from Role Description}\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"FALSE\" RelationshipDeleteBehavior=\"None\" ID=\"{This is the Id of this column} StaticName=\"ProjectRoles\" Name=\"ProjectRoles\" />",
            "targetListName": "Role Description",
            "addToDefaultView": true
        }
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and please upvote it.